# Synchronization mode of ha replication

Tags: activemq-artemis

Version : ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.1

When we use ha-policy and replication, is the synchronization mode between the master and the slave full synchronization? Can we choose full synchronization or asynchronization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what you mean by "full synchronization" so I'll just explain how the brokers behave...

When a master broker receives a durable (i.e. persistent) message it will write the message to disk and send the message to the slave in parallel. The broker will then wait for the local disk write operation to complete as well as receive a response from the slave that it accepted the message before it responds to the client who originally sent the message.

This behavior is not configurable.

Comment: Thanks. Does the master broker send the response that it accepted the message to the producer AFTER the master broker receives the response from the slave broker?